# Kotlin - Most idiomatic way to convert a List to a MutableList

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a method (`getContacts`) that returns a `List<Contact>` and I need to convert this result to a `MutableList<Contact>`. Currently the best way I can think of doing it is like this:

```
val contacts: MutableList<Contact> = ArrayList(presenter.getContacts())
```

Is there a more idiomatic/"less Java" way to do that?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Consider using the [`toMutableList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html) function:

```
presenter.getContacts().toMutableList()
```

There are `toMutableList()` extensions for the stdlib types that one might want to convert to a mutable list: `Collection<T>`, `Iterable<T>`, `Sequence<T>`, `CharSequence`, `Array<T>` and primitive arrays.

Comment: Not only for Collection, but also for Iterable, Sequence, Arrays, CharSequence.

Answer (score 15):

If you only wants ArrayList, you can create your own Kotlin extension.

```
fun <T> List<T>.toArrayList(): ArrayList<T>{
    return ArrayList(this)
}
```

Then you can use it in your application like

```
myList.toArrayList()
```

Simple and easy

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `toTypedArray()` if you want to convert a `List` or `MutableList` to Array

```
/**
 * Returns a *typed* array containing all of the elements of this collection.
 *
 * Allocates an array of runtime type `T` having its size equal to the size of this collection
 * and populates the array with the elements of this collection.
 * @sample samples.collections.Collections.Collections.collectionToTypedArray
 */
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
public actual inline fun <reified T> Collection<T>.toTypedArray(): Array<T> {
    @Suppress("PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN")
    val thisCollection = this as java.util.Collection<T>
    return thisCollection.toArray(arrayOfNulls<T>(0)) as Array<T>
}
```

### Example

```
myMutableList.toTypedArray()
```