# Get MutableList<MutableList<Int>> from List<List<Int>> in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I have a List<List> and need to form a mutable list of lists out of it.

```
fun trial (check: List<List<Int>>): Int {
   val mutableCheck : MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = //mutableListOf(check)?
}
```

I tried various ways, but not able to make it work.

Comment: use ``toMutableList()`` method to convert any list to mutable

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682918/kotlin-most-idiomatic-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-mutablelist
The only difference is the nested lists, which can be handled with a `map`.

Answer (score 2):

`val mutableCheck = check.map { it.toMutableList() }.toMutableList()`